# Jensen Inequality Euclidean Norm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I'm trying to prove $$\mathbb{E}\|X\|\geq \|\mathbb EX\| $$ for any random matrix $X$ and the spectral norm $\|\cdot \|$. To finish my proof all I need is the same statement for the euclidean norm $|\cdot|$ of a random vector $v$:
$$\mathbb{E}|v|\geq |\mathbb Ev|$$
But I am stuck trying to prove this. I am familiar with the one-dimensional Jensen inequality. Am I simply missing the right application of it here?

Comment: Try to prove it in the one-dimensional case first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any unit vector $u$ we have $\mathbb E |v| \geq \mathbb E  \langle u,v \rangle = \langle u,\mathbb Ev \rangle $. The supremum of the right side over all unit vectors $u$ is equal to $|\mathbb E v|$.